# Pneumatically operated three way valves

Tags: valves

I basically need to replace these valves with a modern equivalent

[image]

It’s a pneumatically actuated three way valve for high pressure and flow rate (200 bar, 50 liters/minute). The liquid is basically glue and has a high fouling potential.

What is this type of valve called. Is a high pressure 3 way ball valve suitable here?

Comment: Well, it must be suitable because it worked originally.... are you looking for a direct replacement, an equivalent or something never before used for that purpose which might work? If the latter you need to make sure you know every characteristic of the system and also any proposed replacement device.

Comment: Ideally I’d just use the same type of valve, but that particular valve is nearly 40 years old. I’m having trouble finding something similar. Thought I’d ask to see if anyone knows of an equivalent

Comment: First steps would be 1) hunt for documentation to find out type, vendor etc of existing valve 2) talk to plant staff if the valve worked well in the application. If the valve is basically ok, see if you can have a new actutator mounted,

Comment: The 3-way is to facilitate flushing/cleaning? By "3-way valve", do you mean a 4/3 valve (4 port, 3 position, with the center port of the triplet side plugged, this is often referred to as 3-way), or just a 3/2 valve (3 port, 2 position?) Look thru catalogs from e.g. SMC, Burkert, Festo, Swagelok etc / maybe specialty suppliers for viscous process fluids - calling up sales people for distributors of the previous names might help

Comment: It's a 3/2 valve. Searching for pneumatically actuated ball valves does not give any results for a thing like that. It's obviously a diaphragm of some sort. I though there could be a good reason why it has a diaphragm. Otherwise any other high pressure ball valve would probably be fine.